# Tailwind CSS breakpoint not functioning on flex-col/flex-row

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, tsx, react-tsx

I just started writing frontend with react and tsx, and I am struggling on the CSS of the NavBar, where the responsive design is not working, the flex box cannot change from flex-col to flex-row when the width exceeds.

here is the code

```
<div className="**flex flex-col md:flex-row** md:h-20 bg-[#FFF4E2]  gap-4 text-[#9b6f39] font-bold text-xl" >
      <a href="/" className="self-center flex h-20 w-20">
        <img src="../bin/logo.png" className="max-w-[80px]" />
      </a>
      {menuItems.map(e => {
        return <a href={e.link} className="self-center hover:border-b-2 border-[#B48853]">
        <button>{e.page}</button>
      </a>
      })}
      <div className=" self-center flex-grow mr-2 rounded-lg items-end flex justify-end">
        <a
          className=""
          href="https://forms.gle/PyQufp352yzmygPD8"
          target="_blank"
        >
          <button className=" text-white text-right bg-[#9F5C5C] rounded-lg p-2 hover:drop-shadow-lg">
            登記個案/導師
          </button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

below are my dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/recommended": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.16.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.43.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.24",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3",
    "vite": "^4.3.9"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double-asterisks around the `flex flex-col md:flex-row`. This is because the class names would be `**flex` and `md:flex-row**` but these would not be selected by the Tailwind class names of `flex` and `md:flex-row` respectively since they need to be exact matches:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:h-20 bg-[#FFF4E2]  gap-4 text-[#9b6f39] font-bold text-xl" >
  <a href="/" class="self-center flex h-20 w-20">
    <img src="../bin/logo.png" class="max-w-[80px]" />
  </a>
  <a href="e.link" class="self-center hover:border-b-2 border-[#B48853]">
    <button>{e.page}</button>
  </a>
  <a href="e.link" class="self-center hover:border-b-2 border-[#B48853]">
    <button>{e.page}</button>
  </a>
  <a href="e.link" class="self-center hover:border-b-2 border-[#B48853]">
    <button>{e.page}</button>
  </a>
  <div class=" self-center flex-grow mr-2 rounded-lg items-end flex justify-end">
    <a
      class=""
      href="https://forms.gle/PyQufp352yzmygPD8"
      target="_blank"
    >
      <button class=" text-white text-right bg-[#9F5C5C] rounded-lg p-2 hover:drop-shadow-lg">
        登記個案/導師
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry it's actually the BOLD function of stackoverflow, but not my original code. Would it be the problem of the tailwind version that I am working on?

Comment: From my knowledge, it should work for Tailwind v2 or v3.

Comment: You can check my dev dependencies, the funny thing is that it is working on grid (in another component), but not on flex.

Comment: Yes, it also works in the snippet above. If it does not work for you, consider checking `flex-row` is a valid Tailwind class (check you have not disabled the `flexDirection` core plugin) and also check the file that the code is in is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration.

Comment: the problem fixed after I deleted output.css and build it again, thanks for the help ;)